# Array of structure pointers pointing to NULL automatically?

Tags: c

Do array of structure pointers point to NULL automatically/without being initialized? I would assume not, but it seems to be operating in that manner in the following line of code:

`for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)`

np is a structure pointer, and s is a string.

None of the elements in `hashtab[]` have even been initialized when the loop begins. Every time I run the program the loop terminates immediately because `hashtab[]` contains `NULL`

The full code is below.

```
struct nlist {       /* table entry: */
    struct nlist *next;   /* next entry in chain */
    char *name;           /* defined name */
    char *defn;           /* replacement text */
};

unsigned hash(char *s)
{
    unsigned hashval;

    for (hashval = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;
    return hashval % HASHSIZE;
}

/* lookup:  look for s in hashtab */
struct nlist *lookup(char *s)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)
    if (strcmp(s, np->name) == 0)
        return np;     /* found */
    return NULL;           /* not found */
}
```

Comment: How and where is `hashtab` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `hashtab` is global, it *is* initialized with default values (assuming it's an array and not a dynamically allocated pointer), including `NULL` for pointer types.  This is only for globals or locals declared `static`.

Answer (score 2):

calloc() function will initialize the memory with zeroes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char array[100]; // - initialized by zeroes
void main(void)
{
    char array2[100]; // - initialized with random values
    static char array3[100]; // - initialized by zeroes and allocate not in the stack
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, where is `hashtab` defined? I don't see its definition in the code you posted.

If `hashtab` array is an object with *static storage duration*, then it is guaranteed to be zero-initialized at program startup. Otherwise, it is not initialized at all. All objects with static storage duration are zero-initialized at program startup.

The code you posted suggests that `hashtab` is defined as an external object, which probably means that it is indeed an array with static storage duration. That explains why it is initialized with null pointers by default.